# Performing operations on a NumPy arrray but masking  values along the diagonal from these operations

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

as I can perform operations on arrays so that does nothing on the diagonal
is calculated such that all but the diagonal

```
array ([[0.,  1.37, 1.,   1.37, 1.,   1.37, 1.]
       [1.37, 0. ,  1.37, 1.73, 2.37, 1.73, 1.37]
       [1. ,  1.37, 0. ,  1.37, 2. ,  2.37, 2. ]
       [1.37, 1.73, 1.37, 0. ,  1.37, 1.73, 2.37]
       [1. ,  2.37, 2. ,  1.37, 0. ,  1.37, 2. ]
       [1.37, 1.73, 2.37, 1.73, 1.37, 0. ,  1.37]
       [1. ,  1.37, 2. ,  2.37, 2. ,  1.37, 0. ]])
```

to avoid the NaN value, but retained the value zero on the diagonal in all responses

Comment: What are you trying to do?  What is the operation involved?  Are you trying to do matrix multiplication or inversion?  Your question is very unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder if masked arrays might do what you want, e.g.,

```
import numpy as NP
A = NP.random.random_integers(0, 9, 16).reshape(4, 4)
dg = NP.r_[ [NP.nan] * 4 ]  # proper syntax is 'nan' not 'NaN'
dg = NP.diag(dg)
A += dg                     # a 4x4 array w/ NaNs down the main diagonal
NP.sum(A, axis=1)           # doesn't work, gives: array([ NaN,  NaN,  NaN,  NaN])  
from numpy import ma as MA
Am = **MA.masked_invalid**(A)
NP.sum(Am, axis=1)         # now it works (treats 'nan' as 0)
```

The other way to do this of is, of course, to first convert the NaNs to 0s then
mask the 0s:

```
NP.nan_to_num(A)
MA.masked_equal(A, 0)
```

Finally, it's often efficient to mask and convert the NaNs in one step:

```
MA.fix_invalid(A)
```

Pretty straightforward, just keep in mind that 'ma' might not yet be in your namespace and also that these functions deal with 'NaNs' **and** 'infs', which is usually what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> arr = [
... [0.,  1.37, 1.,   1.37, 1.,   1.37, 1.],
... [1.37, 0. ,  1.37, 1.73, 2.37, 1.73, 1.37],
... [1. ,  1.37, 0. ,  1.37, 2. ,  2.37, 2. ],
... [1.37, 1.73, 1.37, 0. ,  1.37, 1.73, 2.37],
... [1. ,  2.37, 2. ,  1.37, 0. ,  1.37, 2. ],
... [1.37, 1.73, 2.37, 1.73, 1.37, 0. ,  1.37],
... [1. ,  1.37, 2. ,  2.37, 2. ,  1.37, 0. ]
... ]
>>> for i in range(6):
...     for y in range(6):
...             if (i <> y):
...                     print arr[i][y]*arr[y][i]
...
1.8769
1.0
1.8769
1.0
1.8769
1.8769
1.8769
2.9929
5.6169
2.9929
1.0
1.8769
1.8769
4.0
5.6169
1.8769
2.9929
1.8769
1.8769
2.9929
1.0
5.6169
4.0
1.8769
1.8769
1.8769
2.9929
5.6169
2.9929
1.8769
```

Depends on what you need to calculate

Answer (score 1):

Do your calculation as normal and then

```
myarray[arange(len(array)), arange(len(array))] = 0.
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you just do the calculation as normal, then afterwards set the diagonal back to zero?

Comment: Then do this after each calculation: for i in range(len(array)):array[i][i]=0